# Package to enable php from command line, and execution of bgr processes with exec

Tags: lamp

I've ubuntu 12.04 running LAMP.

Script requirements are:

```
Ability to run PHP from the command line (CLI) with exec()
Ability to execute background processes with exec("binary > /dev/null &")
```

For the first should I install php-cli? or some other package? And for the second one, can anyone explain what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to run PHP scripts from command line, the php5-cli package is required.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

**exec** function is implemented in a PHP core (http://php.net/manual/function.exec.php), executing process in a background is realized by your shell (it's not related to PHP or any PHP  modules)

Answer (score 0):

```
  sudo apt-get install php5
  sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
  sudo apt-get install apache2
```

All above commands will install php and apache on your server and you will get the ability to run php commandline also.

Comment: I have all these installed. What is php-cli package than in repo?

Comment: php-cli is command line for php.

Comment: php -v If you see ‘cli’ somewhere on the first line, you are ready to go, otherwise you will have to install it first. apt-get install php-cli